# C# System.Windows.Forms.KeysConverter.ConvertToInvariantString returns localized string

Tags: c#

I am trying to store (and later load) keyboard-shortcuts using strings into a configuration file.

I am working on a german machine and my systems culture is de-DE.
Of course that gives inconsistent conversion results when compared with other systems, as for example the `Ctrl` key is called `Strg` in german.
Therefore I want to store the strings after converting with the InvariantCulture.

I am trying to convert from the Keys Enum to string using the KeysConverter class:

```
var conv = new KeysConverter();
var out = KeysConverter.ConvertToInvariantString(Keys.Control | Keys.M);
MessageBox.Show(out);
```

But this just outputs `Strg+M` instead of the expected `Ctrl+M`.

I also tried using

```
var out = KeysConverter.ConvertToString(null, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Keys.Control | Keys.M);
```

which gave me the exact same result.

Probably I am totally misunderstanding something, but at the moment I just can't wrap my head around it.
Does someone have a hint on what I am doing wrong or could explain this behavior to me?

Thanks and kind regards,
iSnackyCracky

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/issues/2886) is worth reading. Believe me. Especially read the conclusive analysis by weltkante at the end.

Comment: Thanks @OguzOzgul. If I understand that correct, the KeysConverter.ConvertToInvariantString is just bugged and always uses CurrentUICulture for conversion. Right?

Comment: That's right. I actually dived into the source code of it and saw it myself before finding this issue, which is actually opened for .net core side of it but tailed to the .Net Framework. Whatever I had done (changing the UI culture, changing the culture) did not help.

Comment: By the way, some side notes. Documentation says you should not create an instance of KeysConverter directly, but should use GetTypeConverter(typeof(Keys)). It creates the same object. What I saw in the source code: KeysConverter does not implement ConvertToInvariantString but just calls ConvertToString with Culture.InvariantCulture, however, the Initialize method loads (or has already loaded) the key names using the current culture and if the converted type is Keys, the culture information passed to this method is not used at all! Very unfortunate.